# Compression table column status does return in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have created a table like below

```
create table table_name
(
id int,
name varchar(50) ENCODE lzo
)
distkey(id);
```

and after creation I'm checking the column compression and key status by using below query

```
select "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey
from pg_table_def where tablename = 'table_name';
```

but it returned 0 rows .. can anyone know why this is happening

Comment: Is there _anything_ in that table? eg `SELECT * FROM pg_table_def`

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this could be happening.  A couple are - you created the table in one session and forgot to commit the changes, then checked pg_table_def in another session.  Or, since queries to pg_table_def are limited to tables in your search_path, you could be creating the table in a place outside of your search_path.

Comment: Since OP is creating a table, which is a DDL, a commit shouldn't be needed.

Comment: No longer true in Redshift.  (Most) DDL statements can now be inside transactions and do not perform an implicit commit.  This includes CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE. Since the new table isn't visible to other session before commit, pg_table_def needs to seem unchanged to these other sessions as well.